SSRS 2016 Database Renaming issue
A predecessor made a mess of a previous SSRS upgrade to SQL Server 2016 and we're stuck with the database named as ReportServer_New (and ReportServer_NewTempDB). My manager has asked if it can be renamed to ReportServer (and ReportServerTempDB) as it should have been.
I took a backup of the databases, restored them to the same instance and repointed SSRS to these databases using the SSRS Configuration Manager, including restoring the encryption key.
I can navigate the reports and list parameters get populated from their database but the reports won't render. I get an "Internal Error" which isn't very helpful.
Why hasn't a backup of the database brought it back to life? What have I forgotten?
Can anybody suggest where I should start looking to make it work properly?

Hi, what reports do not render? Where are you getting the error?

Wouldn't it have made more sense to rename the database, not backup and restore them?

This question is not about programming. You may want to try https://serverfault.com

Have you tried renaming it via the Configuration Manager?

What have I forgotten? That there are a number of objects in both databases that use 3-part naming to reference across database boundaries. See also: Naming conventions for the report server databases which says, Renaming a report server database isn't supported because the report server databases are considered internal components.
